# PostgreSQL - copying numeric value from jsonb field to integer column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE survey_results (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    publish_id integer,  
    raw jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb
);

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, raw)
    VALUES (1, '{"survey": {"publish_id": 5}}');
```

I want to copy value from jsonb field to integer column with the following update:

```
UPDATE survey_results SET publish_id = raw#>>'{survey, publish_id}';
```

But this returns me:

```
ERROR: column "publish_id" is of type integer but expression is of type text Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. Position: 40
```

How can I fix that?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c50f2/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[just cast](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c50f2/6)?

```
UPDATE survey_results SET publish_id = (raw#>>'{survey, publish_id}')::int;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

> Get JSON object at specified path as text

so you need to cast text to integer to match column data type